# How to configure Symfony project to listen to port 80 of Web Server

Tags: webserver, symfony-1.4, apache-config

I have build a web project in Symfony 1.4 and ORM as Propel. we have a VPS to host our web site, I have created my project on web server and configured it with the IP on port no 8080,
like http://s.o.m.e.i.p:8080. it works fine, but we bought a Domainname as "mysite.com" and it is pointing towards the web server ip i.e http://s.o.m.e.i.p. How can i configure my Symfony Project to http://s.o.m.e.i.p so that it will point the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not doable only in Symfony - you have to alter your apache configuration to use port 80.

Comment: is there any documentation to do that??